# Processing 3.0 method PVector.get() is deprecated

Tags: java, methods, processing

ran into some trouble with my code.

```
PVector vel;
vel = new PVector(random(-5, 5), random(-5, 5));
PVector center = vel.get();
```

Processing is hating on me due to .get() being a deprecated method. The only solution i found is to change it to .copy()
But then i'm getting grief that the function copy() does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to look to the [Processing API](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/). The `get()` function is indeed deprecated, in favor of the `copy()` function.

It sounds like you aren't actually using the latest version of Processing. I would try uninstalling and reinstalling the latest version of Processing, just to make sure.